# Pyspark/Python data frame multiple columns not equal to

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in pyspark.

df.columns

```
['id', 'name', 'date', 'city']
```

df1 = df[[i for i in list(df.columns) if i != 'date']]

when I do df1.columns, I get

```
['id', 'name', 'city']
```

test_df = df[[i for i in list(df.columns) if i != 'date' 'city']]

when I do test_df.columns, I am getting

```
['id, 'name', 'date', 'city']
```

instead of

```
['id', 'name']
```

why is this happening? what is the correct method to use != for multiple columns.

I don't want to use df.select method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test_df = df[[i for i in list(df.columns) if i not in ['date', 'city']]]
```